# Django: At the view level, can I add a 'noindex' header to a 'redirect' response?

Tags: redirect, django-views, view, noindex

I can use robots.txt, and I can use custom Django middleware, but I'd like to know whether this is something that can be done at the view level.

Comment: Adding `noindex` fora a redirect response makes little sense.  Search engines don't index redirects.  Having `noindex` on a redirect is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are probably going to be doing this quite often, you could make it into a decorator.

decorators.py

```
def robots(content="noindex, nofollow"):
    
    def _method_wrapper(func):
        
        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            response['X-Robots-Tag'] = content
            return response

        return wrap
        
    return _method_wrapper
```

views.py

```
from .decorators import robots

@robots("noindex")
def something(request):
    return HttpResponse("")

@robots("all")
def something_else(request):
    return HttpResponse("")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Class Based Views, you can also create a mixin:

**mixins.py**

```py
class NoIndexRobotsMixin:
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex'
        return response
```

**views.py**

```py
class MyView(NoIndexRobotsMixin, generic.View):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a noindex tag using the following snippet:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

response = HttpResponse("Text only, please.", content_type="text/plain")
response['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex'
return response
```